# every list item contains current date and time

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my **MainActivity.class** code for adding value to the list item.
I want to add every item with current date and time in singleItem .

**issue:** My code gives current date and time but in new entry.
how can i solve it?

```
 h_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String message = h_text.getText().toString();

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

                if (message.trim() != "" && currentDateandTime.trim()!="") {
                    list.add(0, message);
                    list.add(0,currentDateandTime);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    h_text.setText("");


                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: are you looking for message and currentDate in one list item?

Comment: I think English is not your mother language.Please ask question more clearly.

Comment: yes. massage and date in one list item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only single item you can not use add like this :

```
list.add(0,currentDateandTime);
```

It will move 1st element to 2nd position and then add new element at 1st position.
So whenever you will use that line it will add one more item in list.

You can try with `list.remove(0)` it will remove item at 1st position and then use     `list.add(0,currentDateandTime)`

Comment: I want to keepboth items massage and date in single listitem. your code is remove massage from item

Comment: If you want both data then you should use model class, and store object of it in list

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a custom listview the [viewholder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a HashMap or a List of list.

I would suggest you to go with list of lists, if you not sure about uniqueness of key as hashMap store values in the key,value pair format.

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

List<String> yourdataList = new ArrayList<String>();
yourdataList.add(message);
yourdataList.add(currentDateandTime);

list.add(yourdataList);
```